# Themes mess up any time I install anything in wine

Tags: gnome, windows, themes

Every time I remove or install anything to do with Microsoft, either it be fonts or dependencies for wine.

I constantly find my theme messing up. Does anyone know why this happens?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine should not do anything to the Ubuntu theme. I think you should file a bug report with Wine. http://bugs.winehq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're replacing an Ubuntu font with a Windows font with the same name? Please, see this note, which is in the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`:

> NOTE: the package ttf-liberation
>   contains free variants of the Times,
>   Arial and Courier fonts. It's better
>   to use those instead unless you
>   specifically need one of the other
>   fonts from this package.

Best regards.